# method specific authentication in Phil Sturgeons php codeigniter rest api

Tags: php, api, authentication, rest, codeigniter

Hi
I know that I can set the rest authentication in Phil Sturgeons rest API, but I only want authentication for some methods in the REST API.

I want some of my methods to be accessible for everyone with no authentication at all, and others to only be accessible to administrators/people authenticated users.

In .net I can simply set a [RequiresAuthentication] attribute over methods in a webservice, is there something similar I can do with Rest PHP in CodeIgniter?

Or Controller specific would be fine too.

Comment: Have you looked at the most recent version on GitHub? You can use API Keys to specify permissions levels for specific methods, so some could be public and some would be private.

Comment: Hi Phil - thanks so much for noticing - I must not be completely aware of how to use this feature. I've tried to do some search for an hour, but I can't seem to find documentation for how to use the apikey function. Is it rest api specific or a general codeigniter feature? Can you give an ultra short example of how I would require users to log in to use specific methods, while having no login at all on others or point to some documentation - I really appreciate your work, it's been of much help to me.

Comment: Not a problem, I subscribe to #codeigniter here. I didn't get around to documenting this (a client paid me to write the code, but not the docs ;-) )but it's pretty easy. Look at the rest.php config file to get the example schema for api keys. Then you can just set specific methods with the protected $methods property. If you look in the example keys controller you should get the idea.

Comment: Also - how safe is it to use api-key instead of authentication? I'm interested in having some methods that don't require login, that any anonymous guest can use and some that are only allowed by administrators that should have to log in.

Comment: @Phil Sturgeon - is the above possible?

Comment: Yes the above is possible, I told you that it was! Make your keys nice and long and they won't be guessed. Perfectly safe as long as nobody shares them around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"philsturgeon Phil Sturgeon 
Why do people ask questions about my code on StackOverflow and random forums instead of just asking me?"

Go ask Phil Sturgeon.

Comment: thx. In my defense I will say that I did spent time trying to find solutions. i.e in the inconclusive http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/159098/#766632 in which Phil participates himself. Which lead me to believe that perhaps a thread in a another place might been a good idea.

Comment: Heh, thanks whoever that was. You already have more reputation than plenty of other members ;) That thread died off as using Digest for advanced api protection gets to be an arse. Using keys is much more manageable.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Jakob :) What you are trying to do is a bit tricky as Phil Sturgeons rest API Controller only supports setting the authentication method globally. To set it globaly you edit this line in the rest config file:

```
$config['rest_auth'] = '';
```

I have an untested theory though:
To set this setting per controller make sure the setting in the config file is as above (empty) and add this constructor to the controller you would like to specify authentication method for:

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->load->config('rest');
    //$this->_prepare_basic_auth(); //Uncomment to use basic
    //$this->_prepare_digest_auth(); //Uncomment to use digest
    parent::Controller();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I had tried such a method myself, but no matter what I get:

Fatal error:  Call to private method REST_Controller::_prepare_digest_auth()

It seems I can't call that method from the a child